# Career advice: Java Developer vs OIM,OAM (IDM)

Tags: career-development, careers, career-switch

I have a question regarding. I’m a java developer and since 6 months i have been working on OIM (Oracle identity manager), OAM (Oracle access maneger) (IDM: Identity management) . I would like to know your opinion on: if i’m better off as a java developer than working on IDM?
In terms of career, salary etc.

Thanks a lot,
Sash

Comment: What are OIM, OAM, and IDM? Independent Data Manager, Internet Dance Master, Original Answer Machine, Optional Interesting Machines and a bunch of other things come to mind for what those acronyms could mean.

Comment: Career advise questions are usually considered off-topic here, because they are 1. very subjective and 2. usually highly specific to the personal situation of the asker, so they provide almost no value for future visitors.

Comment: I know people in both fields that make tons of money.  Which do you like better?  Which are you better at?  If you are a great Java developer and find Oracle stuff tedious, I'd stay away from Oracle,.... even if it pays more.

Comment: @L_7337 I like both of the fields. But i believe there are lot many java developer's out there and it's difficult to demand more salary from employer. And if i'm right, identity management is a special skill and so might pay me well. Am i wrong?

Comment: Can you demand more for a special skill?  Yes,... when the market is good.  But when the market is not as good, you may have a harder time finding a job.  My only advice would be to pick one and put all your effort into developing that skill.

Answer (score 2):

**Adult:** What do you want to be when you grow up?

**Child:** Happy!

**Adult:** You didn't understand the question.

**Child:** You didn't understand life!

The answer to any career advise question is highly subjective and depends on your personal situation and circumstances. It's impossible to tell which career-decision will lead to more salary and an easier career in the long-term, especially in a business which is as dynamic and changing as IT.

So the only advise one can give you is: **Pick the job you enjoy more**.